How can implement less frequent empty block and instant confirmation for transactions by modifying babe consensus?
async fn propose_with(
        self,
        inherent_data: InherentData,
        inherent_digests: Digest,
        deadline: time::Instant,
        block_size_limit: Option<usize>,
    ) -> Result<Proposal<Block, PR::Proof>, sp_blockchain::Error> {
        let block_timer = time::Instant::now();
        let mut block_builder = BlockBuilderBuilder::new(&*self.client)
            .on_parent_block(self.parent_hash)
            .with_parent_block_number(self.parent_number)
            .with_proof_recording(PR::ENABLED)
            .with_inherent_digests(inherent_digests)
            .build()?;

        self.apply_inherents(&mut block_builder, inherent_data)?;

        // TODO call `after_inherents` and check if we should apply extrinsincs here
        // <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14275/>
        

        let end_reason = self
            .apply_extrinsics(&mut block_builder, deadline, block_size_limit)
            .await?;

        // Retrieve the last block time from storage
        let mut storage = BLOCK_TIME_STORAGE.lock().unwrap();

        let last_block_time = storage.get("last_block_time").cloned().unwrap_or(0);
        let current_time = SystemTime::now()
            .duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .as_secs();
        if block_builder.extrinsics.len() > 1  || current_time - last_block_time > 1750 {
            let (block, storage_changes, proof) = block_builder.build()?.into_inner(); // after 1800 sec block production stops
            let block_took = block_timer.elapsed();

            let proof = PR::into_proof(proof)
                .map_err(|e| sp_blockchain::Error::Application(Box::new(e)))?;

            self.print_summary(&block, end_reason, block_took, block_timer.elapsed());

            // Update the last block time in storage
            storage.insert("last_block_time".to_string(), current_time);

            Ok(Proposal {
                block,
                proof,
                storage_changes,
            })
        } else {
            info!(" No extrinsics in the block at {} (parent: {})", self.parent_number, self.parent_hash);
            Err(sp_blockchain::Error::Storage(
                "No extrinsics in the block".to_string(),
            ))
        }
    }
    ```

